# SIMILARITY function triggered by Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I'm implementing TrigramSimilarity full text search on my Django app. I installed the pg_trgm extension by migrating using Django. I can see the migration in my postgres table and I can use the SIMILARITY function when I run queries directly on the database. I get this error when I try to run a search on my app.

[image]

I'm at a loss for what to do because when I get the error with this:
[image]

but when I run a query directly on the database I get results:
[image]

Initially I was using SearchQuery string in place of 'test' but changed it because I saw another answer suggesting that may be a problem.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html the error says your function prototype is  similarity(char var[], unknown). can you try to make sure 1st argument to text, second argument cast to  text explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As jian suggested, I had to explicitly typecast the parameters of the TrigramSimilarity even if I was passing in a string. Hopefully this is helpful to others.